# Creating a calendar component with moment and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, momentjs

I was searching for React Calendar component I found this fiddle however I am not understanding some part of code in that, below is the link

[JSFiddle Link for calendar component code](https://jsfiddle.net/o52wmmnd/)

I did not understand below part

```
monthRange.by('days', function(moment) {
  var ref;
  if (ref = moment.week(), indexOf.call(weeks, ref) < 0) {
    return weeks.push(moment.week());
  }
});
```

which lib is that ".by" using, I ve included moments, moment-range, react-with-addons, but the above method is returning weeks with length 0.

when I debug, I am not able to go into that method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, if you are looking for a ready solution use [react-big-calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html). If you want to build a calendar as a part of a project to learn React look at a simpler code like [holiday-calendar](https://github.com/varadchoudhari/Holiday-Calendar)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [react-big-calender](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html), personally I feel this is much better than create your own.